# Rounding down to increments Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, rounding

I am trying to write a code that rounds down the `start` list values to the nearest .25 value. How would I be able to do that?  So the first index in the `start` list is `3.645` and that would be rounded to `3.5` since `.0, . 25, 0.5, 0.75` are the only increments for `0.25`. Since the last index already is a multiple of 0.25 `2` stays as `2`.

```
start = [3.645, 33.54656, 1.77, 1.99, 2]
```

Expected output:

```
[3.5, 33.5, 1.75, 1.75, 2]
```

Comment: def x_round(x):
    return round((x*4)/4)

Answer (score 2):

This being Python, there's probably some fancy package that will let you do this, but  `[int(4*x)/4 for x in start]` is one way to do it. You can also do `[x - x % .25 for x in start]` (the modulus operator does work for non-integer modulus).

However, I notice you had your last number be just `2`, rather than `2.0`. If you want integers to not be cast as floats, you'll have to do something more complicated, such as `[int(x) if int(x) == x else int(4*x)/4 for x in start]`. And if you want numbers to be cast as `int` if they're integers after the rounding, it will have to be even more complicated, such as `[x - x%.25 if x%1 > .25 else int(x) for x in start]`